# App created using Pyinstaller unable to run due to pyqtgraph colormap issue

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have a simple script that uses pyqtgraph to create a heatplot animation. I receive no error messages when converting it to an .app using pyinstaller. However, when attempting to run the .app from the command line using

```
./dist/MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication
```

I obtain the error message ending with

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:   
 '/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/_MEIsQn9RL/pyqtgraph/colors/maps/CET-D1'
```

Within my script, the line where I define my colormap is what's causing the error:

```
 colorMap = pg.colormap.get("CET-D1")
 bar = pg.ColorBarItem( interactive=False,values=(0,1)  , colorMap=colorMap)
```

Removing the line where I define `colorMap` and removing the `colorMap` argument appearing in the next line, eliminates the problem and the .app runs fine. Of course, the result is an animation where all heatplots appear in default-grayscale.

All I want is a simple colorbar--nothing fancy. Is there a different approach to defining my colorMap that might work, or is there something I might add to my `.spec` file so that the file is found?

Answer (score 0):

```
colorMap=pg.colormap.getFromMatplotlib('jet')
```

permits me to use a standard matplotlib cm , which is satisfactory for my purposes.